# Multi threaded transactional inserts with spring data jdbc

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-jdbc, spring-transactions

I'm using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate. I need to inserts data to 5 different tables within a transaction.

The sequential execution of inserts take long time & I need to optimize the time taken for inserts.

One possible option is make all inserts parallel using threads. As far as I understood transaction is not propagate to multi threads.

How can I improve time taken for this operation within a transaction boundary ?

Comment: Simple. You can't. At least not with threads.

Comment: Are there any other way to improve performance without threads in this case ?

Comment: Improve the inserts. Are you trying to add so much data or why it took so long?

Comment: Hardware tuning, server tuning and insert tuning. If you aren't experienced with JDBC or your database, the last one can probably give you huge improvements once you learn about batching, insert rewriting and whatever all the other features are that your DB offers (I suggest a lot of searching. otherwise you'll be asking questions that have been asked before, and you'll get worse answers).

Comment: Don't use `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` but rather the plain `JdbcTemplate`. The former does String manipulation to replace the named parameters with JDBC placeholders. Also 5 queries shouldn't be that slow unless you do a lot of them.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think what you are trying to do can possibly work.
As far as I know a database transaction is always bound to a single connection.
And the JDBC connection API is blocking, i.e. you can only execute a single statement at a time. So even when you share the Spring transaction across multiple threads you'll still execute your SQL sequential.

I therefore see the following options which might be combined available to you:

1. Tune your database/SQL: batched inserts, disabled constraints, adding or removing indexes and so one might have a effect on the execution time.
2. Drop the transactional constraint.
   If you can break your process into multiple processes you might be able to run them in parallel and actually gaining performance.
3. Tune/parallelise the part happening in your Java application so you can do other stuff while your SQL statements are running.

To decide which approach is most promising we'd need to know more about your actual scenario.